# Is there a Send To imgur app somewhere?

Tags: windows-xp, send-to, imgur

I upload images to Imgur quite often.  I'd love to be able to right-click on an image, select Send To/Imgur and shoot the file up to Imgur.

Does something like this exists?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.  Found it.

http://imguruploader.codeplex.com/releases/view/40965